# Non matching number Regex in Qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I am working on a number parser for q Qt calculator. I have create a few regex in order to match with the different kinds of number:

Rationnal : `^[+-]?\d+\/[+-]?\d+$`

Integer  : `^[+-]?\d+\.?0*$`

Real : `^[+-]?\d*\.0*[1-9][0-9]*$`

Complexe : `^[+-]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*|\/[+-]?[0-9]+)?\$[+-]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*|\/[+-]?[0-9]+)?$`

I try to use them with the following fuction on QString:

## parser.h :

```
     bool isRationnal(const QString s)
{
    QRegExp ratioExp ("^[+-]?\d+\/[+-]?\d+$");
    return ratioExp.exactMatch(s);
}
bool isInteger(const QString s)
{
    QRegExp regExp ("^[+-]?\d+\.?0*$");
    return regExp.exactMatch(s);
}
bool isReal(const QString s)
{
    QRegExp regExp ("^[+-]?\d*\.0*[1-9][0-9]*$");
    return regExp.exactMatch(s);
}
bool isComplex(const QString s)
{
    QRegExp regExp ("^[+-]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*|\/[+-]?[0-9]+)?\$[+-]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*|\/[+-]?[0-9]+)?$");
    return regExp.exactMatch(s);
}
bool isNumber(const QString s){
   bool ok=false;
   s.toInt(&ok);
   return ok;
}
```

---

## main.c :

```
QString test ="6/90";
    if(isReal(test))
        printf("real\n");

    if(isInteger(test))
        printf("Integer\n");

    if(isRationnal(test))
        printf("Rationnal\n");

    if(isNumber(test))
        printf("Number\n");
    else printf("et merde\n");
    QRegExp ratioExp ("^[+-]?\d+\/[+-]?\d+$");
    QRegExp IntExp ("^[+-]?\d+\.?0*$");
    QRegExp RealExp ("^[+-]?\d*\.0*[1-9][0-9]*$");
    QRegExp CplxExp ("^[+-]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*|\/[+-]?[0-9]+)?\$[+-]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*|\/[+-]?[0-9]+)?$");
    if(ratioExp.isValid())
        printf("ratio valide\n");

    if(IntExp.isValid())
        printf("int valide\n");
    if(RealExp.isValid())
        printf("real valide\n");
    if(CplxExp.isValid())
        printf("cplx valide\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to run this code with several QString which are numbers, but it usually fail. Especially : it doesn't mathc with number if there is only one caracter like test="4".

Do you know why are those boolean function failing? Maybe I am using the wrong Qt function but after trying several this one looks like what I am searching for.

Feel free to give constructive critism,

Thank you very much,

Théophile

Comment: Your integer test appears to accept a decimal point. And you need to escape your back-slashes

Comment: Although this is probably not causing your problem, but `exactMatch()` already encloses the regex with the start of string and end of string anchors, so there is no need to put them.

Comment: Indeed, the test for integer must accept numbers like "3.0", they will be converted into 3.
Escaping back slash? I am going to look into this. How do I do that? By double backslash?

Comment: The back-slash `'\'` in `C++` is an escape character so to put a back-slash into a string it needs to escape itself `'\\'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression is fine, but replace `\d` with `\\d`. Tested you code in my program.
And I really recommend to [this site](https://www.debuggex.com/) which can debug your expression online.

Details from [Qt Official Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) :

> **Note**: The C++ compiler transforms backslashes in strings. To include a
>   \ in a regexp, enter it twice, i.e. \. To match the backslash
>   character itself, enter it four times, i.e. \\.

Comment: : )And there are other abbreviations for sets of characters you need double back-slash such as `\\s` `\\w` `\\b`... look deep into Qt document.